# Save session data to table

Tags: php, mysql

I am after two bits of advice for a project I am working on and would really appreciate any advice you may have..

I have the below code and its working really well as a shopping cart for a student project. At the end of the code, I would like to save all the items added to the shopping cart in the table at the bottom  to a MySQL table called orders for example.

Is this possible to do?

Also, for each item for sale on the page there is an image. Is it possible hover over the image and the description from the MySQL table is shown in a hover box?

```
<?php   
 session_start();  
 $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "WineCellar");  
 if(isset($_POST["add_to_cart"]))  
 {  
      if(isset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]))  
      {  
           $item_array_id = array_column($_SESSION     ["shopping_cart"], "item_id");  
           if(!in_array($_GET["id"], $item_array_id))  
           {  
                $count = count($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]);  
                $item_array = array(  
                 'item_id'               =>     $_GET["id"],  
                 'item_name'               =>     $_POST["hidden_name"],  
                 'item_price'          =>     $_POST["hidden_price"],  
                 'item_quantity'          =>     $_POST["quantity"]  
            );  
            $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$count] = $item_array;  
       }  
       else  
       {  
            echo '<script>alert("Item Already Added")</script>';  
            echo '<script>window.location="Shop.php"</script>';  
       }  
  }  
  else  
  {  
       $item_array = array(  
            'item_id'               =>     $_GET["id"],  
            'item_name'               =>     $_POST["hidden_name"],  
            'item_price'          =>     $_POST["hidden_price"],  
            'item_quantity'          =>     $_POST["quantity"]  
       );  
       $_SESSION["shopping_cart"][0] = $item_array;  
  }  
 }  
 if(isset($_GET["action"]))  
 {  
  if($_GET["action"] == "delete")  
  {  
       foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)  
       {  
            if($values["item_id"] == $_GET["id"])  
            {  
                 unset($_SESSION["shopping_cart"][$keys]);  
                 echo '<script>alert("Item Removed")</script>';  
                 echo '<script>window.location="shop.php"</script>';  
            }  
       }  
  }  
 }  
 ?>  
 <!DOCTYPE html>  
 <html>  
  <head>  
       <title>The Wine Cellar</title>  
       <script src="style/jquery.min.js"></script>  
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/bootstrap.min.css" />  
       <script src="style/bootstrap.min.js"></script>  
  </head>  
  <body>  
       <br />  
       <div class="container" style="width:700px;">  
            <h3 align="center"><img src="Images/slide1.jpg" width="644" height="176"></h3>
            <p align="center"><br />  
            <?php  
            $query = "SELECT * FROM tbl_product ORDER BY id ASC";  
            $result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);  
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)  
            {  
                 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))  
                 {  
            ?>  
            </p>
            <div class="col-md-4">  
                 <form method="post" action="shop.php?action=add&id=<?php echo $row["id"]; ?>">  
                      <div style="border:1px solid #333; background-color:#f1f1f1; border-radius:5px; padding:16px;" align="center">  
                           <img src="<?php echo $row["image"]; ?>" class="img-responsive" /><br />  
                           <h4 class="text-info"><?php echo $row["name"]; ?></h4>  
                           <h4 class="text-danger">$ <?php echo $row["price"]; ?></h4>  
                           <input type="text" name="quantity" class="form-control" value="1" />  
                           <input type="hidden" name="hidden_name" value="<?php echo $row["name"]; ?>" />  
                           <input type="hidden" name="hidden_price" value="<?php echo $row["price"]; ?>" />  
                           <input type="submit" name="add_to_cart" style="margin-top:5px;" class="btn btn-success" value="Add to Cart" />  
                      </div>  
                 </form>  
            </div>  
            <?php  
                 }  
            }  
            ?>  
            <div style="clear:both"></div>  
            <br />  
            <h3>Order Details</h3>  
            <div class="table-responsive">  
                 <table class="table table-bordered">  
                      <tr>  
                           <th width="40%">Item Name</th>  
                           <th width="10%">Quantity</th>  
                           <th width="20%">Price</th>  
                           <th width="15%">Total</th>  
                           <th width="5%">Action</th>  
                      </tr>  
                      <?php   
                      if(!empty($_SESSION["shopping_cart"]))  
                      {  
                           $total = 0;  
                           foreach($_SESSION["shopping_cart"] as $keys => $values)  
                           {  
                      ?>  
                      <tr>  
                           <td><?php echo $values["item_name"]; ?></td>  
                           <td><?php echo $values["item_quantity"]; ?></td>  
                           <td>$ <?php echo $values["item_price"]; ?></td>  
                           <td>$ <?php echo number_format($values["item_quantity"] * $values["item_price"], 2); ?></td>  
                           <td><a href="shop.php?action=delete&id=<?php echo $values["item_id"]; ?>"><span class="text-danger">Remove</span></a></td>  
                      </tr>  
                      <?php  
                                $total = $total + ($values["item_quantity"] * $values["item_price"]);  
                           }  
                      ?>  
                      <tr>  
                           <td colspan="3" align="right">Total</td>  
                           <td align="right">$ <?php echo number_format($total, 2); ?></td>  
                           <td></td>  
                      </tr>  
                      <?php  
                      }  
                      ?>  
                 </table>  
            </div>  
       </div>  
       <br />  
  </body>  
 </html>
```

Thanks in advance

Shane

Comment: Yes that's both possible

Comment: To answer your first question ---> yes.

Comment: Yes and definitely yes

Comment: any tips on how this may be achieved. Fairly news to this so eager to learn.